# Merging max cumsums by group and year into new table

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I want to generate cumulative sums by group and year, then copy the cumulative sums for each group and year into a new dataframe that will be used to generate a stacked area chart using `ggplot`.

***Source dataframe:***

So far, I've generated cumulative sums grouped by each year and model using `cumsum` of a column of 1s that I created for each new individual:

```
df$count <- 1
df <- df %>% group_by(model) %>% mutate(cs_model = cumsum(count))

# My source data are thus:

# Groups:   model [4]
    year model count cs_model
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
 1  1876     1     1        1
 2  1885     3     1        1
 3  1937     2     1        1
 4  1939     1     1        2
 5  1950     1     1        3
 6  1960     1     1        4
 7  1969     1     1        5
 8  1971     3     1        2
 9  1973     2     1        2
10  1974     3     1        3
```

For a full copy:

```
structure(list(year = c(1876, 1885, 1937, 1939, 1950, 1960, 1969, 
1971, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1977, 1977, 1979, 1979, 1981, 1982, 1984, 
1984, 1984, 1984, 1986, 1988, 1989, 1989, 1989, 1990, 1990, 1990, 
1990, 1991, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1993, 1993, 1993, 1993, 1994, 1994, 
1995, 1995, 1995, 1996, 1996, 1996, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 
1997, 1997, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 
1999, 1999, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2002, 
2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2004, 2004, 2004, 
2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 
2008, 2008, 2008, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 
2011, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
2014, 2014, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), model = c(1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 
2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 
2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 
3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 
2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, 1, 2, 3, 
NA), count = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
), cs_model = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 2, 3, 6, 4, 5, 7, 8, 
9, 3, 10, 11, 4, 5, 12, 13, 14, 15, 6, 16, 17, 7, 8, 18, 19, 
20, 21, 22, 23, 9, 6, 24, 25, 26, 27, 7, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 
33, 34, 10, 11, 8, 35, 36, 37, 9, 38, 39, 40, 41, 12, 13, 10, 
42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 14, 15, 48, 49, 50, 16, 11, 51, 52, 17, 
12, 53, 54, 13, 55, 56, 57, 58, 14, 15, 59, 60, 61, 18, 16, 62, 
63, 17, 64, 65, 18, 66, 67, 68, 69, 19, 20, 70, 21, 22, 71, 19, 
20, 21, 72, 73, 23, 24, 22, 74, 75, 25, 76, 77, 78, 79, 26, 23, 
24, 25, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 27, 28, 29, 26, 
27, 28, 29, 90, 91, 92, 30, 31, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 1, 98, 99, 
30, 32, 2)), row.names = c(NA, -163L), groups = structure(list(
    model = c(1, 2, 3, NA), .rows = list(c(1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
    11L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 18L, 19L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 27L, 28L, 
    31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 44L, 45L, 
    46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 
    65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 78L, 79L, 82L, 
    83L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 96L, 97L, 99L, 100L, 
    102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 108L, 111L, 115L, 116L, 120L, 121L, 
    123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 
    137L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 
    156L, 157L, 159L, 160L), c(3L, 9L, 17L, 20L, 21L, 26L, 29L, 
    30L, 37L, 51L, 52L, 62L, 63L, 71L, 72L, 76L, 80L, 94L, 106L, 
    107L, 109L, 110L, 117L, 118L, 122L, 127L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 
    161L), c(2L, 8L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 38L, 43L, 53L, 57L, 64L, 
    77L, 81L, 84L, 89L, 90L, 95L, 98L, 101L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 
    119L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 144L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 151L, 152L, 
    162L), c(158L, 163L))), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

As you can see, the cumulative sum for `model = 3` at `year = 1974` is 3: 1 *(1885)* + 1 *(1971)* + 1 *(1971)* = 3 for `model = 3` up to 1974. The cumulative sum for `model = 2` at `year = 1973` is 1 (1937) + 1 (1973) = 2.

This is fine, but there are some years where multiple individuals of a single model are included in one year, so the cumulative sums for each `model` and `year` should be the max:

```
# Groups:   model [3]
    year model count cs_model
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
 1  2003     1     1       51
 2  2003     1     1       52
 3  2003     2     1       17
 4  2003     3     1       12
 5  2004     1     1       53
 6  2004     1     1       54
 7  2004     3     1       13
 8  2006     1     1       55
 9  2006     1     1       56
10  2006     1     1       57
11  2006     1     1       58
12  2006     3     1       14
13  2006     3     1       15
```

I've tried to isolate the maximum unique values for each year and model in `df` using:

`df2 <- df %>% group_by(year, model) %>% mutate(cs_uniques = max(cs_model))`

I believe this is a good start but I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way to go about this or where to go from here, particularly with regard to merging these into the dataframe below.

***Output dataframe:***

To create the stacked area chart, I want create a dataframe `years_area` that includes three rows for each year, one row for each model within a year. This includes *all* years from 1876-2019, including years where there are no observations for those years in the source.

```
years_area <- as.data.frame(rep(1876:2019, times = 3)
names(years_area)[1] <- c("year")
years_area <- years_area %>% arrange(year)
years_area$model <- rep(1:3, times = 3)

# A tibble: 12 x 2
    year model
   <int> <int>
 1  1876     1
 2  1876     2
 3  1876     3
 4  1877     1
 5  1877     2
 6  1877     3
 7  1878     1
 8  1878     2
 9  1878     3
10  1879     1
11  1879     2
12  1879     3
```

I want to create a new column in `years_area` with the cumulative sums in `df` for each model and each year. I'm having trouble because:

1. not every year includes a new individual for each model
2. some years include multiple new individuals within each model, so the cumsum within each year needs to be the highest unique for that year and model
3. there are many gaps in the original time series. `df` includes only years where a new individual was created; `years_area` includes all years from 1876-2019.

**Edit for clarity:**

Expected output for `years_area` is as follows, **using random numbers for the sake of providing a more illustrative example**:

```
   year model cs_model
1   1876     1       1
2   1876     2       0
3   1876     3       3`
```

Where in 1876, there was 1 new `1`, 0 new `2`, and 3 new `3`

```
   year model cs_model
4   1877     1       2
5   1877     2       1
6   1877     3       6
```

Where in 1877, there was 1 new `1` (1+1 = 2), 1 new `2` (0+1 = 1), and 3 new `3` (3 + 3 = 6)

```
   year model cs_model
7   1878     1       4
8   1878     2       1
9   1878     3       10
```

Where in 1878, there were 2 new `1` (2+2 = 4), 0 new `2` (1+0 = 1), and 4 new `3` (6+4 = 10)

```
   year model cs_model
10  1879     1       6
11  1879     2       3
12  1879     3       14
```

Where in 1879, there were 2 new `1` (4+2 = 6), 2 new `2` (1+2 = 3), and 4 new `3` (10+4 = 14), etc.

Comment: Can you use `dput` for `df`. Try with `left_join` i.e.e `left_join(years_area, df %>% select(year, model, cs_model))`

Comment: I believe the issue here would be that some years have multiple (different) values of `cs_model` for each year and model. Additionally the years that are in `years_area` but not `df` would be NA — I'd like for them to repeat the last value `cs_model` until a new individual is added and the value increases.

The different structures of the data are throwing me off...

Comment: YOu can use `left_join(years_area, df %>% select(year, model, cs_model)) %>% fill`

Comment: may be add a group by as well `left_join(years_area, df %>% select(year, model, cs_model)) %>% group_by(year) %>% fill(cs_model)`

Comment: Close — but I'm getting some duplicate `model` values within each `year`:

`# A tibble: 17 x 3
# Groups:   year [3]
    year model cs_model
   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
 1  1996     1       28
 2  1996     1       29
 3  1996     1       30
 4  1996     2       30
 5  1996     3       30
 6  1997     1       31
 7  1997     1       32
 8  1997     1       33
 9  1997     1       34
10  1997     2       10
11  1997     2       11
12  1997     3        8
13  1998     1       35
14  1998     1       36
15  1998     1       37
16  1998     2       37
17  1998     3        9`

Comment: Can you sshow the expected output.  I was using only your example dataset

Comment: Expected output would be the `years_area` df with a new column `cs_model_unique` with cumulative sums for each model and each year. Holes in the data (e.g. each row for the year 1888) would be filled w the last value for each model from the previous year.

Comment: The code above does that, if there are dupes, then these dupes must be coming from the duplicate values in both datasets.  May be you need to join on `distinct` dadta

Comment: Please update your post with the expected output.  It would make it easier

Comment: Added to original post. Many thanks, akrun!

Comment: In the data for 'df', I find only `1876     1     1        1`. How did you get `1876     3       3` in output

Comment: The values in the expected output are random ones I added for the sake of providing a more illustrative example, since there isn't much movement in the first 50  years of the data.

Comment: Ok, I just wanted to check where the logic is incorrect.  If the data is not reproducible, then I can't test it

Comment: I've rewritten the question for clarity, and included the a reproducible version of the source data. Thanks